# TEXT EDITING for data processing

Tags: python, sublime-text-3, text-editing, python3, data-validation

I have a question about text editing I have a big text file that contain input list in it as you see the example of that file on the picture. the list look like this:

```
Input
form
jalan
ba-jalan
pem-porut#an
daun #kulu
daun#kulu
tarik-napas
tarik#napas
n-cium #bow
arau/araw
imbaw//nimbaw
dengo | nengo
dodop=am
{di} dalam
di {dalam}
```

What I need is to separate it to different column to the out put as showing on photo ( to prefix, root and suffix) they have - and # between them I need a formula to separate them by - and # or if there is slash / it should take the first part and ignore the word after slash or if the word is inside the {} it should ignore it what I have done is first I define the text example and then run the bellow formula as you see it on the picture first I defined my list like

words = [
'jalan',
'ba-jalan',
'pem-porut#an',
'daun #kulu',
'daun#kulu',
'tarik-napas',
'tarik#napas',
'n-cium #bow',
'arau/araw',
'imbaw//nimbaw',
'dengo | nengo',
'dodop=am',
'{di} dalam',
'di {dalam}'
]

after that I used this formula to split them

for word in words:
m = re.match(r'(?:{[^-#{}/]+})?(?:([^-#{}/]+)-)?([^-#{}/]+)(?:/[^-#{}/]+)?(?:#([^-#{}/]+))?', word)
if m:
print(repr(m.groups()))
else:
print("(no match: %s)" % word)

the result looks like this

(None, 'jalan', None)
('ba', 'jalan', None)
('pem', 'porut', 'an')
(None, 'daun ', 'kulu')
(None, 'daun', 'kulu')
('tarik', 'napas', None)
(None, 'tarik', 'napas')
('n', 'cium ', 'bow')
(None, 'arau', None)
(None, 'imbaw', None)
(None, 'dengo | nengo', None)
(None, 'dodop=am', None)
(None, ' dalam', None)
(None, 'di ', None)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVj55.png) the output of it still has some problem it didn't split the equal = and I also need tab \t between the words second I need new line \n that I couldn't add them on my formula and also there is another question that if want to define my list first how to add quotation '' around the words and how to add comma , between to in a simple way because that example I added manual if we have a big list it's difficult to add manual can anyone help me with that please thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hey first I define my list: words = [
    'jalan',
    'ba-jalan',
]   after that used this formula:  for word in words:
    m = re.match(r'(?:\{[^-#{}/]+\})?(?:([^-#{}/]+)-)?([^-#{}/]+)(?:/[^-#{}/]+)?(?:#([^-#{}/]+))?', word)
    if m:
        print(repr(m.groups()))
    else:
        print("(no match: %s)" % word)   and the result out of this is like this: (None, 'jalan', None)
('ba', 'jalan', None)
('pem', 'porut', 'an')
  so now what I need is first tab between the words not space or comma second adding line after all three words.

Comment: That sort of thing should be added to the original post so that future surfers do not have to scour and attempt to follow a chain of comments.

Comment: We aren't a team. We are volunteers. Also, adding basic punctuation would make your question far easier to understand.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64255142/remove-spaces-from-the-beginning-of-string-from-text-file-on-python